# Log4j incorrect class using Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, spring-aop

I am trying to make an trace logger using AOP programming, simular to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11881870) The problem is that even after getting a new logger like this:

```
final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
```

All logs are still like this:

```
TRACE 2015-11-05 14:35:43,588 LoggingAspect.logMethod(LoggingAspect.java:42) - Some log
```

Instead of:

```
TRACE 2015-11-05 14:35:43,588 MyClass.SomeMethod(MyClass.java:10) - Some log
```

The class to log from does not change. Any suggestions?

Comment: If any of the answer have helped you please accept it to point out the correct solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
joinPoint.getTarget()
```

returns the target object the method is executed on. This **may** be `null` if your object was executed in a static context, I think. But it may be `null`. So do not use it. And as you can see, It behaves a little bit strange (I think it has to do with proxying or subclassing).

You should better use

```
joinPoint.getSignature()
```

to retrieve the signature of the method, containing the defining class. So better use

```
joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType()
```

to retrieve the class for the logger.